# Spring boot security - display customised authentication failed message in web-service call

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to display customised errors when users try to call my web-service with accounts that are either suspended, locked or invalid.

The problem is, whatever I try, the same message keeps coming back: "Full authentication is required to access this resource"

I have my CustomUserDetailsService as thus:

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(CustomUserDetailsService.class);

    private @Autowired CredentialsServiceQuery credentials;
    private @Autowired MemberProfile memberProfile;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User.UserBuilder builder = null;
        try {
            boolean exists = credentials.checkUserExists(username);
            if (exists) {
                memberProfile = credentials.getUserInformation(username);

                builder = User.withUsername(username);
                builder.password(memberProfile.getPassword());
                builder.authorities(getGrantedAuthorities());
                logger.info("User exists: {}", username);
            } else {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException(SpringSecurityMessageSource.getAccessor().getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", new Object[] {username}, "User credentials is wrong"));
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(SpringSecurityMessageSource.getAccessor().getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", new Object[] {username}, "User credentials is wrong"));
            //throw new UsernameNotFoundException("An error occured while trying to find the username, " + username, ex);
        }
        return builder.build();
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(){
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.clear();        
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

        return authorities;
    }

}
```

My security config has the necessary method calls:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().httpBasic().and().cors().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/",
                "/swagger-ui.html",
                "/webjars/**",
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/v2/api-docs",
                "/info");
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("authorization", "content-type", "x-auth-token"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-auth-token"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new
                UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration.applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }

    public AuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider impl = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        impl.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        impl.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        impl.setHideUserNotFoundExceptions(false);
        return impl;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }
```

And finally, my entrypoint:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException ex) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String json = String.format("{\"errorcode\": \"%s\", \"message\": \"%s\"}", response.getStatus(), ex.getMessage());
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(json);
    }
}
```

I understand, in this case, the entrypoint is responsible for composing the error message that gets delivered when the wrong credentials are provided when my web-services are called. So my question is how do I get the entrypoint to deliver a customised message like, "User A's account is locked"?

If the entry point can't do it, is there something else I can do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to abandon the idea of trying to get Spring Security to automatically serve the entry point with exception messages from the User Details Service.

So, instead, I switched to a Custom Authentication Provider for more control, and introduced a custom service called ErrorMessage:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Service
public class ErrorMessage {
    private String status;
    private String message;
}
```

The @Getter, @Setter and @ToString annotations are from lombok. They make it so I don't have to write setters and getters and a toString method.

In my custom authentication provider, I simply set my error messages thus:

```
private @Autowired ErrorMessage errorMessage;    
@Override
        public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
            try {
                String username = authentication.getName();
                String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

                if (!credentials.checkUserExists(username)) {
                    //set something here
                }

                memberProfile = credentials.getUserInformation(username);

                if (passwordEncoder.matches(password, memberProfile.getPassword())) {
                    logger.info("It matches - encoder!");
                    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, getGrantedAuthorities());
                } else {
                    //error message bean utilised here
                    errorMessage.setStatus("100");
                    errorMessage.setMessage(username + "'s password is incorrect");

                    throw new BadCredentialsException("The credentials provided are incorrect");
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException("The credentials provided are incorrect", ex);
            }
        }
```

And then I get the customised error message in the entry point this way:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    private @Autowired ErrorMessage errorMessage;

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException ex) throws IOException, ServletException {
        //String json = String.format("{\"errorcode\": \"%s\", \"message\": \"%s\"}", response.getStatus(), ex.getMessage());
        String json = String.format("{\"errorcode\": \"%s\", \"message\": \"%s\"}", errorMessage.getStatus(), errorMessage.getMessage());
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(json);
    }
}
```